# WordPress Gravity forms with pretty url (url rewrite) on IIS7

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, mod-rewrite, gravity-forms-plugin

We have an issue with a WordPress instance running on an IIS 7 server. Gravity forms are used to ask an user for there information.

When we fill the Gravity form only with information entered by the user it works like a charm. Though, when some information is prefilled in the Gravity form using some extra parameters like `?param1=1&param2=2` the result no entry in the database.

If we disable the WordPress pretty URLs and add the paramaters again to URL the form works again. So, we concluded that it has `something` to do with the rewrite rules. This is as far as our current analysis goes (and my knowledge on IIS's behavior on rewrite rules).

I added the current web.config bellow. Hope that someone can give us a hand.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
      </httpErrors>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The path that doesn't work as expected is
- http://www.greenfields-kunstgras.nl/voetbalvelden/voetbal-kostencalculator/?utm_source=GF+NL+-+Voetbalvelden+-+Optin&utm_campaign=0b940c24f2-GF+NL+-+Voetbal+-+Email1&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_75d85ff960-0b940c24f2-96711629

The path that does work (if pretty urls are off)
- http://www.greenfields-kunstgras.nl/?page_id=2670&utm_source=GF+NL+-+Voetbalvelden+-+Optin&utm_campaign=0b940c24f2-GF+NL+-+Voetbal+-+Email1&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_75d85ff960-0b940c24f2-96711629#gf_2

When you follow the link the initial behavior is, in both cases, as expected. Only when the form is finalized. No records are saved when using the first path.

Comment: And if just as a test you replace `type="Rewrite"` with `type="Redirect"`, where does it take you when you have the extra parameters?

Comment: Then everthing in front of the query parameters will disappear and you will be redirected to the wrong page.

Comment: Do you have an example of path that works and one that doesn't (with the input you have and the expected output)?

Comment: @cheesemacfly added the paths. Hope you got some great ideas.

Comment: What if you change `<match url="*"/>` to `<match url=".*"/>`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly that will result in a 404. Detailed error:
Module: `IIS Web Core`, 
Notification: `MapRequestHandler`
Handler: `StaticFile`
Error Code: `0x80070002`

Comment: you are using the `patternSyntax="Wildcard"`, sorry completely missed that...can you try using the [Failed Request Tracing Tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see if you can find any additional information?

Comment: Nope, I can't I don't have access to the server's configuration other that the FTP.

Comment: And can you access the IIS logs?

Comment: @cheesemacfly logs are for download on http://harx.nl/gf-nl-logs.zip. I will remove them in a few days.

Comment: btw there is an entry on the url in `u_ex130807.log`

Comment: There is 1 thing I don't get. Where does the redirect from `page_id=2670` to `voetbalvelden/voetbal-kostencalculator` happen?

Comment: if this is a form submit, have you tried hidden fields for your parameters? Just as a work-around suggestion, url query parameters then are gone so you don't run into your configuration problem. Also what did your server administrator told you when you asked him about the problem? There might be other rules on that server that prevent this, just saying.

Comment: @hakre server admin told us that there have not been any significant changes to the server lately (this worked before).

Comment: @hakre the parameters are inserted in hidden fields the moment you enter the page

Comment: @cheesemacfly the `page_id=2670` works when the pretty urls are turned off. WP will basically remove the rewrite rules for that.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use PHP (without mod_rewrite) for pretty URLs:
This solution may help you. [Rewrite URL in PHP without htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459854/rewrite-url-in-php-without-htaccess/2460357#2460357)